# How can I automatically sum values that I add from a combo box to a text area?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, textbox, sum

I'm making a kind of shopping cart for a website I'm creating for a web designing class and I already did the part of loading the products into the combo and adding them to the text area when I click the button but now I have to make the ammount of money to pay shows in a texbox automatically after I add all I want but I dont know how to do it, here's the code I'm using:

To load the products names and price:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","paradise_root","gantzminus1");
mysql_select_db("paradise_dbsalon");
$consulta="select precio,nombre from productosyservicios order by nombre asc";
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta);
?>

<?php
                      while($fila=mysql_fetch_row($resultado))
                      { 
                      echo "<option value='".$fila['0']."'>".$fila['1']."</option>";
                      } 
                      ?>
```

and to add what I want into the text area:

```
<script>
$('#btnmas2').click(function(e)
{
var selected=$("#combo option:selected").val();
$('#lista').append("\n"+selected+"\n");
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used in this example the `parseFloat` and `toFixed` methods that I think should answer your needs.
http://jsfiddle.net/gr2cj/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="total" value="0"><br>
<button onclick="add('10.59')">Add 10.59</button>
<button onclick="add('15')">Add 15</button>
<button onclick="add('14.99')">Add 14.99</button>
<button onclick="add('12')">Add 12</button>
<button onclick="add('1')">Add 1</button>
```

JS:

```
function add(price) {
    price = parseFloat(price);
    val = parseFloat($("#total").val()) + price;
    $("#total").val(val.toFixed(2));
}
```

The function converts both value to floats, combine them and convert the result to string.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused couse you're using buttons with assigned values and I'm calling the values of my products from a database It works the same way or I have to change something?

Comment: This is just an example. You can use it in your current function as well. Just make it like `var price = parceFloat($("#combo option:selected").val());` and you'll get your number.

Comment: idk if its the location where I'm pasting it or what but now when I add something it adds twice and in the total textbox show NaN, where should I paste it? cause I tried pasting it in the body and on the head but nothing change 

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btnmas2').click(function(e)
{
    var selected=$("#combo option:selected").val();
    $('#lista').append("\n"+selected+"\n");

    var price = parseFloat($("#combo option:selected").val());
    var val = parseFloat($("#total").val()) + price;
    $("#total").val(val.toFixed(2));
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>

Comment: It was doing it cause I forgot to delete the previous code but now I only let the one you used and its not even showing the values it refresh the page every time I click the button

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. Nothing in this code cause the whole page to refresh. All it does is take a value from one element and pass it into another.

Comment: I know its like it wasnt reading it you know cause if I delete it and press the button happens the same I think its where I'm pasting it, where's the correct place to put javascript code? in the head, in the body, in the title? where?

Comment: This specific code doesn't need to in the footer but it does needs to be places **after** the element are placed in the html page. Otherwise, the script tries to attach the click event to a none-existing element and fails.

Comment: ok now its working but still shows the NaN instead of the total

Comment: I don't know how your code is built so I can't help you there. Use your browser's developer tools to debug your code and find out what went wrong.